# How to get proper filepath from FileResult fileData = await FilePicker.PickAsync();?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using                 FileResult fileData = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
for picking file in xamarin forms app.
But fileData.FullPath is not correct, Can anyone help me for getting proper filePath?

Comment: What do you mean `FullPath` is not correct?

Comment: If I use FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile(); for picking file then it gives fileData.FilePath which is different from FullPath.

FileResult fileData = await FilePicker.PickAsync(); =>
It gives FullPath : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.icampus.iCampusMobile/cache/2203693cc04e0be7f4f024d5f9499e13/bb54fba6bd4444c9b73f4273c4be9b02/IMG-20211217-WA0009.jpg    

which is not correct

Comment: I assume you are using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?tabs=android rather than the outdated CrossFilePicker? Your best bet is to access the stream when you first get the file then write the bytes to your local application directory. That way you can specify the path yourself.

Comment: According to what you said above, the path obtained using FilePicker.PickAsync seems to be the address in your APP. What is the difference between the address you want and it?